# PhD program and article publication without supervisor name

Tags: publications, phd, graduation

Can a PhD student publish an article without the name of the supervisor? if even the supervisor agrees with that?

Comment: It is likely a duplicate, look at the list of "Related" questions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is no general requirement about supervisors. This assumes, of course, that the work is that of the student alone and the supervisor isn't an author.

The advice of the supervisor is fine, and even their help, but ordinary rules of authorship still apply, though these differ somewhat by field.

Comment: Thank you so much for the information.  I have faced a bigger problem than it that I am going to share in another post, and it might be one of the rare cases in academics.